# How do I count pieces of Halloween candy of different shapes?

Tags: words, kanji, counters

I know that a bag of candy is counted as fukuro. Are the pieces counted differently based on the shape, long, thick, square, round, triangular, or is everything ko?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would use [個 (こ)](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%80%8B).  That should work alright for what you are trying to do.

Comment: maybe i cound use tsu as well.

Comment: Of course, I don't think it needs saying, but generic counters will work.

Comment: There's a very [useful guide](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/japanese-counter-ko/) by Tofugu about this counter.